# Missing navigation menu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am an amateur, developing my website using Wordpress. In the Mobile version the navigator drop down suddenly stopped showing up. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Thought it may be just my phone. Checked many phones, it not just mine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.